# Fill in missing rows in a table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a report that needs the top 18 id codes for each case. Some cases only have all 18 rows and some only have a few. Here is an example of the output:

```
Case       idcode          value
 2            3             122
 2            6              52 
 2            15            121
 3            1             111 
 3            3             555
 3            6             322
```

What I need the output to have is 18 rows per record (idcodes 1-18) and to put "none" for the value if it is added. What is the best way to add in the missing rows if I do not know which ones are missing ahead of time?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    rcl.CaseCaseId as Case, cce.StringValue as Value, cce.CorpIdCodeId as idcode
FROM         
    CaseIdCodeEntry AS cce 
INNER JOIN
    CorpIdCodes AS cid ON cce.CorpIdCodeId = cid.CorpIdCodeId 
INNER JOIN
    PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_542 AS rcl ON cce.CaseCaseId = rcl.CaseCaseId
WHERE
    (cce.CorpIdCodeId < 19)
```

Comment: This is not quite clear! do you need `idcode` column 1-18? I can see `idcode` value been duplicated here. So what will determine the missing value and how?

Comment: I need the output to have a row for each id code. For example case 2 is missing id code 1, 2, 4...... I need to add those missing numbers in and assign "none" as the value.

Comment: So you need 1-18 `idcodes` per each `case` value then?

Comment: Case 2 should have 18 rows, case 3 should have 18 rows. Any case in the output should have 18 rows. Each row is idcode 1,2,3....18.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a recursive CTE to auto-generate a numbered list of 1-18, and then LEFT JOIN off of that. Then use a CASE statement to adjust the Value field.

```
;WITH cte AS
(   SELECT DISTINCT CaseCaseId AS CaseID, 1 AS idcode
    FROM PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_542 UNION ALL
    SELECT CaseID, idcode+1 FROM cte WHERE idcode < 18 )
SELECT  cte.CaseID AS [Case], 
        CASE WHEN cce.CorpIdCodeId IS NULL THEN 'None' ELSE cce.StringValue END AS Value, 
        cte.idcode AS idcode
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN CaseIdCodeEntry cid ON cid.CorpCodeId = cte.idcode
LEFT JOIN CorpIdCodes cid ON cce.CorpIdCodeId = cid.CorpIdCodeId
LEFT JOIN PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_542 rcl ON cce.CaseCaseId = rcl.CaseCaseId
```

Comment: ;WITH cte AS
(   SELECT DISTINCT CaseCaseId AS CaseID, 1 AS idcode
    FROM PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_542 UNION ALL
    SELECT CaseID, idcode+1 FROM cte WHERE idcode < 18 )
SELECT  cte.CaseID AS [Case], 
        CASE WHEN cce.CorpIdCodeId IS NULL THEN 'None' ELSE cce.StringValue END AS Value, 
        cte.idcode AS idcode
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN CaseIdCodeEntry cce ON cce.CorpIdCodeId = cte.idcode
LEFT JOIN CorpIdCodes cid ON cce.CorpIdCodeId = cid.CorpIdCodeId
LEFT JOIN PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_542 rcl ON cce.CaseCaseId = rcl.CaseCaseId
order by CaseID, idcode

Comment: This is what my query looks like now but it is still not putting the missing id codes in.

Comment: I think there needs to be some tweaking in the JOINS, but I'm fuzzy on the table structures. If you run just the contents of the CTE, you should have all required [Case] and [IDCode] values, so adjust your joins based on that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this seems works fine

```
create table #temp(iCase int, idcode int,value int)
Insert into #temp values(2,3,122)
Insert into #temp values(2,6,52)
Insert into #temp values(2,15,121)
Insert into #temp values(3,1,11)
Insert into #temp values(3,3,555)
Insert into #temp values(3,6,322)


create table #Val(Id int)

declare @count int =1

while (@count<=18)
begin
    insert into #Val values(@count)
    set @count=@count+1
end

DECLARE @CaseId INT
DECLARE @DataCursor CURSOR
SET @DataCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT distinct iCase
From #temp
OPEN @DataCursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM @DataCursor INTO @CaseId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #temp
    SELECT @CaseId,Id,null
    FROM #Val
    WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT idcode
    FROM #temp
    WHERE iCase=@CaseId )

FETCH NEXT
FROM @DataCursor INTO @CaseId
END
CLOSE @DataCursor
DEALLOCATE @DataCursor


Select * from #temp
```

Comment: How do I do this with an existing table instead of #temp. This solution assumes known values which I will not know ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82af3/4)

Like Jon of All Trades I also favour the use of a sequence (or number) table.

```
CREATE TABLE Seq ( seq_num int)
```

You can use this to populate the missing rows from your original data; assuming you have a table `T` holding your data

```
CREATE TABLE T ( case_num int
                ,code_id int
                ,value char(4))
```

You can use the following query to get your fully populated results

```
WITH All_Codes AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT case_num, seq_num AS code_id
    FROM T, Seq
)    
SELECT All_Codes.case_num
  ,All_Codes.code_id
  ,CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 'none' ELSE value END AS value
FROM All_Codes LEFT JOIN T 
  ON All_Codes.case_num = T.case_num AND All_Codes.code_id = T.code_id
```

The result is

```
case_num  code_id  value
2         1        none
2         2        none
2         3        122
2         4        none
2         5        none
2         6        52
2         7        none
2         8        none
2         9        none
2         10       none
2         11       none
2         12       none
2         13       none
2         14       none
2         15       121
2         16       none
2         17       none
2         18       none
3         1        111
3         2        none
3         3        555
3         4        none
3         5        none
3         6        322
3         7        none
3         8        none
3         9        none
3         10       none
3         11       none
3         12       none
3         13       none
3         14       none
3         15       none
3         16       none
3         17       none
3         18       none
```

Answer (score 1):

Humpty and Matt's solutions should work, but as a purist I'd recommend using a Numbers table rather than a cursor or CTE.  It's simpler (IMHO) and for large quantities it should be significantly faster:

```
SELECT
    X.CaseId, N.Number, X.Value
FROM
    Numbers AS N
    LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT
            CICE.CaseCaseId AS CaseId, CICE.StringValue AS Value, CICE.CorpIdCodeId AS IdCode
        FROM
            CaseIdCodeEntry AS CICE
            INNER JOIN CorpIdCodes AS CIC ON CICE.CorpIdCodeId = CIC.CorpIdCodeId
            INNER JOIN PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_542 AS RCL ON CICE.CaseCaseId = RCL.CaseCaseId
        ) AS X ON N.Number = X.IdCode
WHERE
    N.Number BETWEEN 1 AND 18
```

Incidentally, are you sure you need to join `CaseIdCodeEntry` to `CorpIdCodes` and `ReportCaseList_542`?  If they're there to filter the data, that's fine, but as they're not contributing to the output I have to wonder.

Comment: Yes I have to use it to link the two tables together.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I used. I used some of @Jon of All Trades and @huMpty duMpty code.

```
SELECT     cice.CaseCaseId, cice.CorpIdCodeId, cice.DateValue, cice.DoubleValue, cice.StringValue, cic.Label
into #TT
FROM         CaseIdCodeEntry AS cice INNER JOIN
                      CorpIdCodes AS cic ON cice.CorpIdCodeId = cic.CorpIdCodeId INNER JOIN
                      PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_542 AS rcl ON cice.CaseCaseId = rcl.CaseCaseId
WHERE     (cice.CorpIdCodeId <= 18)
ORDER BY cice.CaseCaseId, cice.CorpIdCodeId


create table #Val(Id int)

declare @count int =1

while (@count<=18)
begin
    insert into #Val values(@count)
    set @count=@count+1
end

DECLARE @CaseId INT
DECLARE @DataCursor CURSOR
SET @DataCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT distinct CaseCaseId
From #TT
OPEN @DataCursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM @DataCursor INTO @CaseId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TT
    SELECT @CaseId,Id,null, null, null, 'none'
    FROM #Val
    WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT CorpIdCodeId
    FROM #TT
    WHERE CaseCaseId=@CaseId )

FETCH NEXT
FROM @DataCursor INTO @CaseId
END
CLOSE @DataCursor
DEALLOCATE @DataCursor


Select * from #TT
order by CaseCaseId, CorpIdCodeId
drop table #TT, #Val
```