# SQL Show data row even when there is no value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to output every date in current month but last year with values for each date, some dates may have 0 so still need to output the result.

SQL Server 2008

I'm currently getting:

```
Day | Value
1   | 500
2   | 437
5   | 976
```

I would prefer:

```
        Day | Value
        1   | 500
        2   | 437
        3   | 0
        4   | 0
        5   | 976
```

Here's my SQL script:

```
SELECT SUM(O_VALUE) AS Value, DAY(O_DATE) AS Day
FROM dbo.table
WHERE (MONTH(O_DATE) = MONTH(GETDATE())) 
  AND (YEAR(O_DATE) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1)
GROUP BY O_DATE
ORDER BY O_DATE
```

Comment: What version of sql-server?

Comment: Then you need to have a table that has all the dates as the basis of your query.

Comment: SQL is not good at "creating" rows to fill gaps.  You can either create a table that includes all possible values of "day" that you can join to, or use a loop in the SQL, which may kill performance.  Also note that filling the gaps in the client layer (report, program, UI) may be MUCH easier than doing it in SQL.

Comment: Definitely NOT a loop. And the where predicates you have are nonSARGable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill in missing rows in a table SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276763/fill-in-missing-rows-in-a-table-sql)

Comment: @Wolrab posted  answer is not solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

i hope this will help you

```
 -- declare the table
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
  d int,
  v int
)

INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1, 500)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2, 437)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (5, 976)

-- Common Table Expression
;WITH Missing (missnum, maxid)
AS (SELECT 1 AS missnum, (SELECT MAX(d)  FROM @temp)
UNION ALL
SELECT missnum + 1, maxid
FROM Missing
WHERE missnum < maxid)

-- select from table and Common Table Expression
SELECT * FROM @temp
UNION
SELECT missnum,0
FROM Missing
LEFT OUTER JOIN @temp tt ON tt.d = Missing.missnum
WHERE tt.d IS NULL
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Not a huge deal on such a small dataset but using a recursive cte to count like this is pretty much the same thing as a loop. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Answer (score 1):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE([Day] INT, Value INT)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1    ,500),
(2    ,437),
(5    ,976)
```

### Query

```
;WITH x AS
 (
  SELECT 1 AS [Days] UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 
  )
SELECT COALESCE(x.[Days] , t.[day]) AS [Day]
       ,ISNULL(t.Value,0) AS Value
FROM x LEFT JOIN @TABLE t   --<-- Instead of this table variable put your query as 
ON x.Days = T.[Day]            --as a sub-query here and join to that
```

### Result

```
╔═════╦═══════╗
║ Day ║ Value ║
╠═════╬═══════╣
║   1 ║   500 ║
║   2 ║   437 ║
║   3 ║     0 ║
║   4 ║     0 ║
║   5 ║   976 ║
╚═════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Thanks @M.ali I am slightly confused :/

Where do I put my query? before yours or after